# Score increasing in x position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and c#. Currently I am going along with brackeys - how to make a video game series. But I am stuck at making the score board. I have copied the same code but don’t know why is it increasing when I am pressing `w` and `s` keys. Here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SCORE : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = player.position.x.ToString("0");
    }

}
```

Can someone point out the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs here, `scoreText.text = player.position.x.ToString("0");`
You need to change it to `scoreText.text = player.position.y.ToString("0");`
so that the score increases when you are moving in forwards direction.

Comment: Oh thanks. actually I am new to programming that’s why I can’t figure it out. But can you tell why is it so

Comment: Maybe because you rotated the cube to some other side. That’s why the score was increasing when you were moving left and right.